# Are signs of early puberty in a primary-school aged child a cause for concern?

Tags: health, development, primary-schooler

My son is less than 6 years old, and last week we discovered that he has grown a little bit of pubic hair. This seems way too soon for this to happen. My older son, who is 9 years old, only now started growing a bit of pubic hair (and this also seems a bit early).
Is this normal? Should we be concerned?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this entry at Michigan's Health System with lots of valuable information and links to more information: http://www.med.umich.edu/yourchild/topics/puberty.htm

Having read this article on Precocious Puberty, if it were my son I would take him to the doctor. There is some concern that Precocious Puberty, puberty earlier than 9 years on in boys, can be caused by an underlying disease.

It seems a check up is in order to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

Six is way too young to begin puberty. Have him evaluated by a physician as soon as possible! The nine-year-old is also on the very young side. I'd have him checked out, too. Precocious puberty can result in [compromised adult height](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4690910/).

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a doctor's appointment is appropriate.  Be sure to not alarm your child with statements of "this is not normal".  Approach the appointment/concern through the lense of health so that your child sees taking care of himself as important.
Good luck